# Return the higher element than the top of the Stack in Java

Tags: numbers, integer, stack

The method nbGreaterThanFirst that returns the number of elements in myStack that are greater or equal than the element on top of myStack. Let's say the top of the stack is 5, and there are elements which are 7, 3 and 9. It should return as 9 since it's greater than the rest of elements in the stack. The steps of the algorithm seems ok to me but it didn't work. Any Suggestions?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class greaterStack {
    public static int nbGreaterThanFirst(Stack<Integer> myStack) {
        int firstStack = myStack.peek(); // firstStack = 5
        for(int i=0; i<myStack.size(); i++) {
            if(myStack.peek() >= firstStack) { // if any element is greater than 5
                firstStack = myStack.peek();
                myStack.pop();
            }
        }
        return firstStack;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        s.push(1);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(7);
        s.push(5);

        System.out.println(nbGreaterThanFirst(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you are poping the element only if top of stack is >= your current firstStack variable. Thus as soon as you get an element with a lower value than your current firstStack value, your algo doesn't allow popping of the element and you stop moving though the stack.

For stack with elements 5, 7, 3, 9 as soon as you hit the "3" it will fail your if condition and no more elements will be popped from the stack. Thus you never will get to the "9" element.

My suggestion is move the pop() out of the if condition. Pop once every iteration so that all the elements are checked.

```
int stackSize = myStack.size();
for(int i=0; i<stackSize; i++) {
        if(myStack.peek() >= firstStack) { // if any element is greater than 5
            firstStack = myStack.peek();
        }
        myStack.pop();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented that before and it still doesn't work. The output was 7, which is incorrect since there's one element which is 9 so that element should be displayed.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Since the size of stack changes on every pop, the mystack.size() in the for loop kept varying and this caused problem. That was causing the loop to quit on the comparison in the third iteration (i kept increasing and stack.size() kept decreasing, so the loop only ran for half the time). Use a local variable to store the size of the stack before entering the loop and use it to compare in the loop

Comment: No problem. Just run a step by step debug and you can clearly see when your algo breaks.